What is the name of the animated Christmas-bible story?
I am sorry that I don't have more information here but I remember clearly of a animated Christmas story I watched during the 80s.  The film could have been made earlier but that is when it aired on television, our local TV station had it every year.
So the facts are:

it covers the story of Jesus being born (what was going on with Mary and David, Bethlehem, wise men...)
a lot of it focused on what happened before birth
its general aim was for kids maybe 5-11
it had a goofy narrator that introduced each scene and was part of the story
it was pretty long.  I would say at least one hour but maybe two.
the narrator was often overlooking the desert/Arabic scene that was in the background - like he was on a hill overlooking the city, and I think usually at night.
I have looked for it since the late 90s on and have not seen it replayed anywhere.  

Edit: I did go through several websites yesterday that had all Christmas movies and shows ever made.  Did not see anything on the list.  Even though it was played every Christmas in my area as a kid (not on big 3 network but the WB - not then WB - equivalent) I don't know if it would be categorized as a Christmas movie due to the religious aspects of the show.  I did find a Lutheran nativity story that was close (animation and period) but for sure not it called Christmas Is.  

@DForck42 - a little man - sorry that is all I have.  If it helps at all the story wasn't overly religious - educational but in a very deceptive way - so it appealed to kids.  The animation was definitely done well and period to 70s/early80s.
